# Stray elm reactor process?

Tags: elm

I've been learning elm (reading [Elm in Action](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwijosCM16zoAhWQhJ4KHb9cCVsQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.manning.com%2Fbooks%2Felm-in-action&usg=AOvVaw3TPlZCBsyQ5SQQvb4d0Fo2)) and it's been going well until just today.

I have just started moving my project from individual pages to an SPA (chapter 8 in the book).  I created a new elm file and modified the html file to point to the new component's 'init', rebuilt, and restarted elm reactor.  Unfortunately the resulting page was blank.  So I fired up the inspector and saw that the page's script block still pointed to the previous elm component I created.  I looked at the html and it points to the correct component but reactor is apparently serving a previous version of the html file.

I closed all windows so there could be no reactor running and tried opening the html file (localhost:8000/index.html) and, sure enough, it shows up - still with the old version.  I then rebooted my laptop and, without bringing up any window or IDE, I brought up firefox and navigated to the same URL and I was surprised to still see the same blank page (no errors).  And it still shows the previous component in the script block in inspector.

I then brought up powershell and navigated to the project directory and ran reactor with --port 8080 and brought up the same index.html file (localhost:8080/index.html) and now I get what I expect to see.  I exit reactor and try this url again and get an error page - as expected.

Apparently I have an old reactor process running somewhere that lives on after a reboot of the PC.  Does anyone have any idea how to track that down and kill it?  I have looked in my Startup Apps, in the Task Manager, and even brought up SysInternals process explorer but can't find this elm/reactor/node anywhere.

Env: Windows 10, Professional; Elm 0.19.1; Node 13.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise.  It was apparently a Firefox cache issue.